# how to call or open online website calculator and fill it automatically for calculation for using in problem in fortran coding?

Tags: fortran, call

in this coding i want to open online website calculator and use that for calculation in this problem. So how can call or open that page in fortran.

```
program propulsion
  implicit none
  real(kind=4):: Mo, g=1.4,M9,a9,V9,gb=1.25, Pin=6.67
  real(kind=4):: Po, Pto, To, Tto,Pt2,Tt2,Pt21,Tt21,Pt3,Tt3is,Tt3,Tt3h,Tt5h,Tt4,Ttcc,Ptcc,Pt4,Tt9,Pt9,P9,T9,Tt4h
  real(kind=4):: teta, delta, pi, neta,y,D,Ma,Z,Mf,Phi,Rb,ra,Cpb,b,rho9,Rhoo,Aro,Ar9,ao,Vo,Tn,Tr,N,x
  integer,parameter::Dn=180
  Real::Cp=1005,Cph=14330,LH2=461000, Ttoh=21,Ro=287,Dst=34.04
  print*,"Enter the value of Mo"
  Read*, Mo
  print*,"Enter the value of Po"
  Read*, Po
  print*,"Enter the value of To"
  Read*, To
  Pto = Po*(1+((g-1)/2)*(Mo)**2)**(g/(g-1))
  Tto = To*(1+((g-1)/2)*(Mo)**2)
  write(*,*)"Pto", Pto,"Tto", Tto
   Tt2=Tto
  if (Mo<=1) then
    Pt2=Pto*0.95
    else
        Pt2= Pto*(0.95-(0.075*((Mo-1)**1.35)))
  end if
  write(*,*) "Pt2",Pt2,"Tt2",Tt2
   if (Mo<=2) then
     Tt21=Tt2
    else
    1 print*,"Enter the value of compressor inlet temperature"
  Read*, Tt21
  end if
   Pt21=0.9*Pt2
    write(*,*) "Pt21",Pt21,"Tt21",Tt21
    teta=Tt21/288
    delta=Pt21/1.013
     N=1/((teta)**0.5)
     Z = (-8.9249*((N)**5))+ (24.139*((N)**4)) - (22.441*((N)**3)) + (8.8606*((N)**2)) -(0.7158*(N)) + 0.0597
    write(*,*) "corrected mass flow rate", Z
    D=z*Dn
    Ma=(D*delta)/((teta)**0.5)
     write(*,*) "Ma",Ma,"delta",delta,"D",D
     write(*,*) "teta",teta
     write(*,*) "N",N
    Y= (0.9937*((Z)**4))-(1.5131*((Z)**3)) + (1.794*((Z)**2))- (0.2253*(Z)) + 0.0155
    write(*,*) "corrected pressure ratio",Y
neta=0.95-((100-(y*100))/240)
    pi=y*Pin
    Pt3=pi*Pt21
    Tt3is=Tt21*((pi)**((g-1)/g))
    Tt3=((Tt3is-Tt21)/neta)+Tt21
    write(*,*) "neta",neta
    write(*,*) "Pt3",Pt3,"Tt3",Tt3,"Tt3is",Tt3is
     2 print*,"Enter the value of Phi"
     Read*, Phi

 if (phi>1) then
    b=(70.64+((phi-1)*2))/(phi+1.8802)
    Rb=8314/b
    else if (phi==1) then
    Rb=338.604
    else
          b=(18*phi+((0.5-((phi)/2))*32)+57.06)/((phi/2)+2.5)
           Rb=8314/b
            end if
  write(*,*) "Rb",Rb
  Mf=(phi/Dst)*Ma
  write(*,*) "Mf",Mf
  ra=Ma/Mf
  Tt5h=Tt3
  Tt4h=(((Tt3-Tt21)*Ma*Cp)/(Mf*Cph))+Tt5h
  if(Tt4h>1200) then
    goto 2
  end if
  write(*,*) "Tt4h",Tt4h
  Cpb=(gb*Rb)/(gb-1)
  if (Mo<=2)then
    Tt3h=Ttoh
    else
        Tt3h=(((ra*Cp*(Tt2-Tt21))-LH2)/Cph)+Ttoh
  end if
  if (Tt3h>1600) then
    goto 1
  end if
  write(*,*) " EXIT TEMPERATURE OF PRE COOLER Tt3h",Tt3h
open(unit=10, file='http://elearning.cerfacs.fr/combustion/tools/adiabaticflametemperature/index.php')
  print*,"Enter the value of Ttcc"
  Read*, Ttcc
  If (Mo<=2) then
    Tt4=Ttcc-((LH2+Cph*(Tt4h-Tt3h))/(Cpb*(ra+1)))
  else
     Tt4=Ttcc-((Cph*(Tt4h-Tt3h))/(Cpb*(ra+1)))
     end if
     if (Tt4>2200) then
        goto 2
     end if
  write(*,*) "Tt4",Tt4
    write(*,*) "Cpb",Cpb
  Tt9=Tt4
  Ptcc=0.95*Pt3
  Pt4=0.9*Ptcc
  Pt9=Pt4
  P9=Po
  M9=((((Pt9/P9)**((gb-1)/gb))-1)*(2/(gb-1)))**0.5
  T9=Tt9*((1+((gb-1)/2)*(M9)**2)**(-1))
  a9=(gb*Rb*T9)**0.5
  V9=M9*a9
  ao=(g*Ro*To)**0.5
  Vo=Mo*ao
  write(*,*) "Ptcc",Ptcc,"Pt4",Pt4
  write(*,*) "Tt5h",Tt5h
  write(*,*) "Tt4",Tt4
  write(*,*) "Pt9",Pt9,"Tt9",Tt9
  write(*,*) "M9",M9,"a9",a9,"V9",V9
  write(*,*) "ao",ao,"Vo",Vo
  write(*,*) "T9",T9,"P9",P9
  Rho9=((10**5)*P9)/(Rb*T9)
  Ar9=(Ma+Mf)/(Rho9*V9)

   Rhoo=((10**5)*Po)/(Ro*To)
   Aro=(Ma)/(Rhoo*Vo)
    write(*,*) "Rho9",Rho9
    write(*,*) "Rhoo",Rhoo
    write(*,*) "A9",Ar9
    write(*,*) "Ao",Aro

     Tn=(((Ma+Mf)*V9)-Ma*Vo)+(A9*(P9-Po))
     Tr=0.5*Rhoo*((Vo)**2)*320*0.03
     x=Tr/Tn
     write(*,*) "Tn",Tn
     write(*,*) "Tr",Tr
     write(*,*) "thrust required by thrust available",x
   close(10)

  end program propulsion
```

Comment: Welcome. It is important to Format the code properly before posting, check the buttons available in the question editor. How is your code relevant to your question? There is no way to interact with web in Fortran directly. Only special libraries may be able to do that. What exactly you want to do? Which calculator? For what purpose?

Comment: To reinforce one of @VladimirF's comments: I think OP will find it easier to re-implement, in Fortran, the calculator, than to interact with it from a Fortran code.  I'm a big fan of Fortran, but I wouldn't use it for conversations with web services.  Well, not unless some kind-hearted but simple-minded employer with deep pockets set me to the task.  And even then I'd wrap up some code written in a more web-friendly language and call it from the Fortran.

Comment: http://elearning.cerfacs.fr/combustion/tools/adiabaticflametemperature/index.php. i want to call this website to open